# Golang creating password protected zip file

Tags: go, zip

I am trying to create password protected zip file in golang using package `archive/zip`. I am not able to find any example that it support creating password protected archive. I came across another library `https://github.com/alexmullins/zip` but last commit on it is 5 years back and I am not sure if it will not create any issue if used in code.

How I can create password protected archive in golang. Does archive/zip can be used to create password protected archive.

Comment: use 7zip with os/exec

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava Which would require an external program.

Comment: I would probably fork the project and use the fork. This way, you can fix bugs should you run into them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now using https://github.com/alexmullins/zip to create password protected zip file.

Comment: It's a great library, but some OS (such as Windows) currently might not handle password-protected zip files created by it. It's not the library's fault, it's just the type and level of encryption that's being applied there.